# Use variable button width using constraint

Tags: ios, constraints

I am using two button and have to give variable width according to iPhone devices e.g. iPhone4, 5 & 6 using constraint, the space of leading, trailing and between two button should be same.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and ask a question to narrow it down.

Comment: If you calculate the widths programmatically, just create the width constraint and assign them IBOutlets (i.e. `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *widthButton1;`) and then set `self.widthButton1.constant = yourWidth;`. Otherwise give us more info so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

For button 1, set leading constraint to left edge of superview, with constant equal to your desired leading spacing.

For button 2, set trailing constraint to right edge of superview, with constant greater than or equal to your desired trailing spacing.

Set horizontal spacing constraint between buttons, with constant equal to your desired spacing.

Select both buttons and create an equal widths constraint to make the buttons have equal width. This is what allows them to expand or contract to fit the screen width.

That should do it. You should not need to create outlets or adjust the constraints programmatically.

Comment: I would love to accept your answer but unfortunately i do not have enough reputation.

Comment: I thought you should be able to accept an answer to your own question. Can you check again?